# MySQL insert on duplicate key update with coalesce() invokes syntax error in java

Tags: java, mysql, syntax-error

I'm trying to do an update, saving the old value if the new one is NULL, SQL query is

```
INSERT INTO scheme (id,type) 
VALUES (1,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE scheme 
SET type=COALESCE(1,type) 
WHERE id=1
```

the error text is

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET type=COALESCE(1,type)
WHERE id=1' at line 4
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
```

I guess that it is just something obvious I'm missing, but I can not figure it out :(

Answer (score 2):

You never need a `WHERE` in a `ON DUPLICATE KEY` query (and it should always break in MySQL) -- the conflicting line has already been found and since there cannot be two of them, you have to update that one. The `WHERE` is implied.

Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO scheme (id,type) 
VALUES (1,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE scheme 
SET type=COALESCE(1,type)
```

Comment: I'm almost certain, that somewhere in the internet I saw an example of `ON DUPLICATE KEY` and there was also `WHERE`. But nonetheless I checked if this way it will work fine and it's not, unfortunately. Still same `check the manual <...> for the right syntax to use near 'SET type=COALESCE(1,type)' at line 4`